# What is IOTA Masked Authenticated Messaging (MAM)?

Tags: iota-network, masked-authenticated-messaging

There have been reports of MAM being implemented on IoT devices like the Bosch XDK and RuuviTag. What, exactly, is MAM?

Answer (score 1):

I think the introduction by the core dev, Paul H, is fairly easy to understand. Have you taken a look? :)
https://blog.iota.org/introducing-masked-authenticated-messaging-e55c1822d50e

Comment: Are there any more details on how the code for developing MAM was done on these devices?

Comment: Edited today to be more specific.

Comment: Not exactly for these devices but there is a deep dive article about MAM code 

https://iotafan.jp/en/developer/deep_drive_into_mam_20171229/